# Not able to add extension in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm using spree 3.0.4 in rails (4.2.3) and ruby (2.2.0).

Now I want to add extension to this. So I add gem

```
gem 'spree_simple_sales',:path => '../spree_simple_sales'
```

in my application, but when I bundle it gives me error like:

```
Could not find gem 'spree_simple_sales (>= 0) ruby' in source at ../spree_simple_sales.
Source does not contain any versions of 'spree_simple_sales (>= 0) ruby'
```

Can you tell why it gives me this error?

Comment: were you able to get this working? having the same problem

Answer (score 4):

you need to specify a version for the gem you are using, like such

```
gem 'spree_simple_sales', '0.1.0', :path => '../spree_simple_sales'
```

Hope this helps, I think a reference to the necessity of specifying a version should be added to the 'Extensions' tutorial on the Spree website.

Answer (score 0):

Just try adding this to your `Gemfile` and bundle

```
gem 'spree_simple_sales'
```

Comment: I think she's trying to following the tutorial on spree website, not the actual gem.

Answer (score 0):

use something like:

```
gem 'spree_simple_sales'
```

Also extension is not compatible as per your spree version and this is not updated for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to edit the file '*spree_simple_sales.gemspec*' by commenting out all the lines, after that bundle install worked.
It also worked the 'rails g spree_simple_sales:install' command.

Answer (score 0):

I added the `summary` and `description` in the `.gemspec` and that made it work.

```
s.summary     = 'spree_simple_sales'
s.description = 'very simple sales'
```